# Удобная форма входа с Loginza на wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите статью, как сделать вход на вордпрессе с логинзой. Желательно, чтобы была как ссылка в модальное окно (типа login box) только, чтобы была возможность размещения в любом месте...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы воспользоваться OAuth авторизацией, обязательно нужен переход на удаленный ресурс и получение CODE, а потом запрос токена. Переход на удаленный ресурс осуществляется по ссылке. Т.е. Вы ушли со своего сайта, а потом на него вернулись. Тут можно организовать всплывающее окно, а не модальное. А всплывающие окна блокируются браузером. Думаю лучше работать стандартным способом.

Если в хедере разместить окошко логинзы и обрабатывать полученный результат в хуке, который выводится на всех страницах сайта, то логинзу можно использовать практически в любом месте.

PS. Как устроен вордпресс не знаю. Попытался ответить в общих понятиях.